# Which Database is suitable for classifieds website?

Tags: mysql, django, postgresql

I'm developing a classifieds website with Django framework, But i don't know which Database is suitable for this project? PostgreSQL or MySQL ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either one will work; the only limitation is your skill.  Which one do you know better?

Comment: Then what's stopping you from using it?

Comment: your right!, i'm sure now, to using it..